# Windows desktop shortcut keeps losing its DPI override setting

Tags: windows, desktop, display, dpi

We have an internal desktop application developed in C# (Windows Forms). One of our users (Windows 10 64-bit) has her display set to 125% zoom (Display settings > Scale and layout). The application was not designed to work at different zoom levels, so we have given the user a desktop shortcut that overrides the DPI to make it look better (Properties > Compatibility tab > Override high DPI scaling behaviour tick-box).

The problem is that this DPI setting on the shortcut is getting periodically reset. The user notices the display issue again and we have to re-tick the box in shortcut properties. Then a few days or weeks later the same thing happens. I have confirmed that the user is not editing or recreating the shortcut.

Why does the DPI setting not "stick" permanently? How can I stop it getting reset?

Comment: Having the same issue. No any clue how to fix it though.